# Replace Div when hover other Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, css-tables

I want to replace the Divs in a table when I move the mouse over different Divs
There is an initial table 2x2 with A,B,C and D.

The cells B, D, F and H are non visible.

They would only appear when you move your mouse over the cells that are already there.

If you move your mouse over cell A, cell C would disapear and would appear D instead.

If you move your mouse over cell C, cell G would disapear and would appear H instead.

If you move your mouse over cell E, cell A would disapear and would appear B instead.

If you move your mouse over cell G, cell E would disapear and would appear F instead.

```
#HTML

<div id="table">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell A">A</span>
        <span class="cell B">B</span>
        <span class="cell C">C</span>
        <span class="cell D">D</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell E">E</span>
        <span class="cell F">F</span>
        <span class="cell G">G</span>
        <span class="cell H">H</span>
    </div>
</div>

#CSS

#table {
    display: table;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
}
.cell {
    width:50%;
    display: table-cell;
    background: red;
}

.B, .D, .F, .H{
    display: none;
    background blue;
}

#JS

$('.row').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.C').hide();
    $(this).find('.D').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.D').hide();
    $(this).find('.C').show();
});
```

I want the content and background of the cells to change.
I tried doing so in CSS only but couldnt find a way to make a Div disapear, tried to look for something here and found the JS method but I cant make it work the way I want.

When I move the mouse over cell A, C disapears and the D does appear but the background doesnt fill the whole cell, and when I move the mouse over cell C it just flickers. It is somewhat a success but I cant figure how I would make the whole table work.

Thanks

Comment: Your css is broken. **background-color: red;**

Comment: The `background: red;` is fine. It's the `background: blue;` that's missing the colon.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I missed it copying the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `.show()` since it's going to set `display` to `inline`, which will not achieve your goal of displaying each `span` as a `table-cell`.

(NOTE: There's a colon missing the CSS -> `background: blue;`)

This is what I came up with:

```
function showAndHide(trigger, item1, item2) {
  $(trigger)
    .on('mouseenter', function() {
      $(item1).hide();
      $(item2).css('display', 'table-cell');  
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
      $(item1).css('display', 'table-cell');
      $(item2).hide();  
    });
}

showAndHide('.A', '.C', '.D');
showAndHide('.C', '.G', '.H');
showAndHide('.E', '.A', '.B');
showAndHide('.G', '.E', '.F');
```

Check out the working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyEstilles/o7Lbr9ox/.

Comment: My pleasure Felipe. :-)

Comment: I added a border to the cells and the background color bleeds through the border. I fixed it putting overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; in the #table{} but when I do the hover thing the new cell always bleeds. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you share the code as you have it right now? (HTML, CSS, JS) It makes it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Strikamos/2gmpekow/1/

I left the lines of the overflow and display inside the #table{} commented so that you can easily spot the color bleed. With those lines uncommented the bleed disapears, except when I move the mouse over and the background changes.

Comment: Felipe, are you using Chrome? If you are, then this is an issue with webkit transforms in Chrome. You can get rid of them by added `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the `#table` `div`. I didn't mention this before because you're original CSS did not transform/rotate the `div`.

Comment: I am using Chrome. The rotation is a last minute change. Thank you again, it does solve the color bleed. But now the text looks a bit blured.

Comment: That is an unfortunate side effect of WebKit transforms in Chrome that has not been fixed yet (see [https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92055](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92055)).

Comment: That does suck. Thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: Any time. Sorry I couldn't be of any further assistance. As a side note: You should consider up voting @stroz's answer (as a courtesy). To be fair, his answer was conceptually close to what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code necessary to do that. I created a method that when the first is hovered, the second disappears and the third takes its place.

Link to working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stroz/exrz0asc/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function registerConditionalHide(first, second, third) {
        $(first).hover(function() {
            $(second).hide();
            $(third).show();
        }, function() {
            $(third).hide();
            $(second).show();
        });
    }

    registerConditionalHide(".A", ".C", ".D");
    registerConditionalHide(".C", ".G", ".H");
    registerConditionalHide(".E", ".A", ".B");
    registerConditionalHide(".G", ".E", ".F");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It does improve my code alot but I find the 1st answer works exactly the way I want it filling the whole cell.

Comment: You're welcome, would you consider upvoting my answer since my logic is clearly used in both solutions?

Comment: Upvoting ... Great minds think alike. :-) We should both get credit.

Comment: I cant for now.. not enough reputation. But definitly will once I can!